# Smart contract update every 60 seconds with Oraclize

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, oracles

I am trying to create a smart contract using geth and ethereum-bridge (Oraclize) on a private network. I want to know the number of visits to a youtube video.
The first time it works correctly but I would like it to extract the number of visits every 60 seconds and the contract will be automatically updated.

How can I do this?

Thanks !!

---

Thanks for answer!

I have tried the recursive contract example in the browser-solidity of oraclize and the first time returns the result but the second time an error:
[image]

I've also tried on geth with ethereum-bridge on a private network and it does not work the second time either.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve that with recursive queries and a 60-seconds delay, read more about scheduling a query in the future [here](http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-schedule-a-query-in-the-future) and see an example of recursive contract [here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/6e18f81e657e38dc014fd38ce566e71917411353/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol#L28)